# $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space f({x})=0$, $|f''(x)| < M$. Prove: $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space f'({x})=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

It's known that:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space f({x})=0$$

$$|f''(x)| < M$$

How do I prove that:

$$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \space f'({x})=0$$

I tried using the mean value theorem, but I don't really know how to approach the question.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772475/show-that-lim-x-to-infty-fx-0-implies-lim-x-to-infty-fx-0).

Comment: Also, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730411/behavior-of-fx-as-x-to-infty-given-the-behavior-of-fx-and-fx).

Comment: I can't find the duplicate with the nice answer: Show that $f'$ is uniformly continuous and that $\int _0^\infty f'$ is finite. This implies your result.

Comment: [Here it is](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849771/prove-that-lim-x-to-infty-fx-0).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMitra. I tried to find a duplicate before posting, but it's difficult to search for those kinds of math questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't see this one in the duplicates..

Proof by contradiction. Suppose not, and there is $\epsilon > 0$ and  $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ such that $|f'(x_n)| > \epsilon$. Since $|f''(x)| < M$, for $x$ in the interval $[x_n, x_n + {\epsilon \over 2M}]$ one has $|f'(x)| > {\epsilon \over 2}$. So by the
mean value theorem, $|f(x_n) - f(x_n + {\epsilon \over 2M})| > {\epsilon \over 2}\times {\epsilon \over 2M} = {\epsilon^2 \over 4M}$. Hence at least one of $|f(x_n)|$ and $|f(x_n + {\epsilon \over 2M})|$ is greater than ${\epsilon^2 \over 8M}$. Letting $n$ go to infinity contradicts the assumption that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Best one I've seen! (But this is robjohn's argument from my second link above.)

Comment: Same basic idea yes.. but I think this is more efficient so I'll keep it here for people to see.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify this: Since |f′′(x)|<M, for x in the interval [xn,xn+ϵ2M] one has |f′(x)|>ϵ2.

Comment: By Taylor (or mean value theorem), $f'(x) = f'(x_n) + f''(y)(x - x_n)$ for some $y$ in the interval. So $|f'(x)| > |f'(x_n)| - |f''(y)(x - x_n)| > \epsilon - M|x-x_n| > \epsilon - M{\epsilon \over 2M} = {\epsilon \over 2}$