# Proof of the Landau-Kolmogorov inequality

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces

Do you know where I can find a proof of the Landau-Kolmogorov inequality claimed in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_inequality) ?

Comment: This may be useful, although it only covers a simple case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57982/a-proof-for-landau-inequality-and-similar-cases